# UIImageView defined in IB has zero size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

A very short question. Created a `UIImageView` in IB with is a `IBOutlet` in its view controller. However, when it look for its its size with `.frame.size` everything seems to be null. It would be nice to be able to set the dimensions in IB and have the code pick up and respond to it. Is there something I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you connect your UIImageView to it's IBOutlet in IB.

Also, the connections with the outlets aren't actually done until viewDidLoad, so you would still see nil if you tried to access the imageview before this method is called.

Comment: yes, just checked this following on from Max's comment above. That is it I think. Fear I have been caught out by this time sequencing before.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain that you haven't connected your IBOutlet with appropriate view in IB.

Comment: I click-dragged the `UIImageView` from the IB onto the `IBOutlet` in the .h file. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint in your viewDidLoad and check whether your image view is not NULL.

Comment: This helped. The viewDidLoad test exposed the issue highlighted by rekle below. Think this must be it.